# table, tabular in next line because it is too weid horizontally

Tags: tables

This is what I want!

[image]

But my code doesn't work, it appears like this

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} % espanol
    \decimalpoint
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % graficos

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{listings}

    \usepackage{tikz} %era para hacer los grafos pero no investigué mucho asi que lo hice con word
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    %Header an Footer Stuff

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }


    %Hyperlink
    \usepackage{varioref}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=false}
    \hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}


    \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
        \caption{Valores optimos Ejercicio 2}   
            \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l |}
            \hline
             $x_{ij}$ & 1-2 & 1-3 & 1-5 & 2-3 & 2-4 & 2-8 & 3-4 & 3-5 & 4-7 & 4-8 & 5-6 & 5-9\\
            \hline
             Valor & 30 & 15 & 14 & 7 & 7 & 16 & 12 & 10 & 7 & 12\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}\hspace{0pt}%
            \begin{tabular}{l l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l |}
            \hline
             2-4 & 2-8 & 3-4 & 3-5 & 4-7 & 4-8 & 5-6 & 5-9\\
            \hline
            1111 & 8 & 5 & 11 & 12 & 28 & 19 & 0\\
            \hline
            \end{tabular}\hspace{0pt}%
        \label{tab:vo-ej2}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: your second code fragment with `... code`  is not useful for anyone debugging your issue, please edit it so that it generates the output that you show,

Comment: however you are only allowing a line break in one place and you have used geometry package to change the page  width, so you appear to need to break at a different column.

Comment: remove those `\hspace{0pt}%`s amd do a line break instead. The table will be set as in your first example then.

Comment: how do I add a line break ? @LaRiFaRi

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't added my code bc it's way long and I just have trouble with that piece of code that I added

Comment: You don't need to post your original document but you should always post an example of the problem. Posting code that does not have the error that you are asking about does not help anyone help you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry man but I don't understand what code you need then, the problem is that when I run the up code it works well, but if I copy the piece of code to put it in my full document it doesn't work in the same way, it appears like in the picture below...

Comment: @EmiliOrtega a line break in LaTeX is added by a blank line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that someone reads and understands your table, you might want to redesign it. What do you think about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Valores óptimos Ejercicio 2}\label{tab:voed} 
    \begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=2.0]}
        \toprule
        $x_{ij}$ & {Valor} \\
        \midrule
         1-2 & 30 \\
         1-3 & 15 \\
         1-5 & 14 \\
         $\vdots$ & {$\vdots$} \\
         4-8 & 12 \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\qquad
    \begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=4.0]}
        \toprule
        $x_{ij}$ & {Valor} \\
        \midrule
         5-6 &  \\
         5-9 &  \\
         2-4 & 1111 \\
         $\vdots$ & {$\vdots$} \\
         5-9 & 0 \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LaRiFRi {c S[table-format=4.0]} those commands belong to ssiunitx ? what does c and S do ? I figured that table-format is to define how large horizontally is my table but I don't get the other ones.. I'm new using latex haha thanks in advance

Comment: @EmiliOrtega the `c` is standard for centered. The `S` belongs to `siunitx`. The `table-format=4.0` is telling the column to expect numbers with 4 digits before the comma and 0 after it. You are right, this fits the horizontal width.